# How to read firestore numeric value to text field in php Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a numeric firestore value called `1_star`. What i trying to do is to retrieve the 1_star value and show it on my text field. But everytime when I want to retrieve it keep showing me error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Numeric separators are not allowed at the end of numeric literal`. My html text id is called `star1`

My code (Javascript):

```
db.collection("PRODUCTS").doc(pageTitle).get().then((doc) => {
    
    if (doc.exists) {
   
        document.getElementById("star1").value = doc.data().1_star;

    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

My firestore value:

[image]

My html :

```
  <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input
                          type="number"
                          class="form-control"
                          id="star1"
                          placeholder="1_Star"
                          name="star1"
                          required
                        />
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the type `text` attribute for your Input field.
You can solve your problem using two methods:

1- Change your input type to number.

2- Convert your data to String using `toString();` function if your data type is a number:

```
db.collection("PRODUCTS").doc(pageTitle).get().then((doc) => {
    
    if (doc.exists) {
   
        document.getElementById("star1").value = doc.data().1_star.toString();

    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Because of you did not share your HTML code I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur respond. I tried with `toString()` but it still show me the same error. I had updated my question with html. You can have a look.

Comment: can you log `doc.data().1_star` and show me the data inside of it?

Comment: I cant even log it, it showing me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Numeric separators are not allowed at the end of numeric literals`

Comment: @WEIZHUANGGOH Im not sure if this will work : `doc.data().1_star.toString().replace('_', '');`

Comment: Yea i tried this method before, but still the same issue :(